ME906s LTE M.2 Module auto disconnect under Ubuntu 22.04
I have a ME906s LTE module connected through USB. The module works alright with Ubuntu 20.04.
But with 22.04 the LTE module instantly disconnects itself. The 22.04 is a fresh install, server version, no desktop environment.
Attached is the dmesg output:
[  797.721578] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  797.870998] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=15c1, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  797.871012] usb 3-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  797.871018] usb 3-9: Product: HUAWEI Mobile V7R11
[  797.871023] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
[  797.871027] usb 3-9: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[  797.878909] cdc_ether 3-9:2.0 wwan0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-9, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 02:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  797.879591] option 3-9:2.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  797.879690] usb 3-9: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  797.880065] option 3-9:2.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  797.880123] usb 3-9: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  797.880458] option 3-9:2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  797.880795] usb 3-9: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  797.881142] option 3-9:2.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  797.881201] usb 3-9: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[  797.881547] option 3-9:2.6: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  797.881601] usb 3-9: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[  797.925175] cdc_ether 3-9:2.0 wwx021e101f0000: renamed from wwan0
[  798.465754] cdc_ether 3-9:2.0 wwx021e101f0000: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-9, Mobile Broadband Network Device
[  798.493706] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  798.493720] option 3-9:2.2: device disconnected
[  798.493815] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[  798.493828] option 3-9:2.3: device disconnected
[  798.494602] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[  798.494642] option 3-9:2.4: device disconnected
[  798.495329] option1 ttyUSB3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
[  798.495341] option 3-9:2.5: device disconnected
[  798.496015] option1 ttyUSB4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB4
[  798.496029] option 3-9:2.6: device disconnected

There is no trace of LTE module in ip link, /dev/
lsusb still shows the module though.
Both regular kernel (5.15 I think) and HWE kernel (6.5) behaves exactly the same.
What is going on with Ubuntu?

The device may just not work with that version of Ubuntu. Maybe contact the makers support and ask them.
